# Significance of Blue Cross used to represent Lord Shiva?

Tags: analysis, tandav

In the recently released Amazon Prime series *Tandav*, there was a scene where they show a play about a comedic interaction between Lord Shiva and Narad.

[image]
[image]

There was some backlash regarding the religious sentiments involved.

But my question is why the blue cross on the face of the actor to portray Lord Shiva?

Comment: My guess would be to show the blue skin of Shiva without actually painting his whole face blue and maybe make it look a bit 'modern' or 'fashionable'. I don't see any other underlying meaning